# Redirecting image requests via .htaccess depending on file existence

Tags: php, .htaccess, file-exists

I implemented an image generator which saves the final file in .**jpg** format inside **/images**. Once the file is saved, there is no need to generate it *ever again*.

This is the route for the image generator:

```
/gen.php?id=495abc
```

This is the directory where all the .**jpg** images are saved:

```
/images/495abc.jpg
```

So, the objective is: If a user tries to request `http://website.com/images/495abc.jpg`, the `.htaccess` rules have to verify if the file exists and then execute one of two actions depending on the case:

1. if the .**jpg** exists, serve the file directly.
2. if the .**jpg** does **not** exist, redirect the request to the generator at `/gen.php?id=495abc` *(the new image will be displayed at the end of this process with `Header("Content-Type: image/jpeg")`)*

*Is that feasible via **.htaccess**? If not, there is another alternative: Redirect all `/images/*.jpg` requests to `/gen.php?id=*` and let **gen.php** do all the dirty work. Of course, the first alternative is better.*

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. It is possible with `htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^images/(\d+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif|ico|bmp)$ /gen.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: I was trying your solution and it was not working and I just realized why. The ID is not necessarily a digit only, it can contain alphanumeric characters (md5 values). What should the **d** value be in that case?