# How to add hash to the image to display the image only if hash exist

Tags: php, .htaccess, hash

I'm wondering how to add hash to the image to display the image only if hash exists?

Here is an existing example where this logic is implemented http://193.0.171.27/13/80/98/1504890831/1531993942_square.jpg?hash=pPGpdsy8NJK1w0sq04Xjzw&expires=64060578000

The image above is displayed only if the hash is present in the url otherwise the image is forbidden.

Is anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: of course you need to add the name before the value...else its invalid

Comment: @Andrew, and how to do it using php?

Comment: @Starkeen, what do you mean? If you mean htaccess can you please give some example?

Comment: I just completed your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I see two possibilities, you can rewrite all your image links and serve it from php, for example like this:

Before:

```
<img src="yourimagefolder/1531993942_square.jpg" />
```

After:

```
<img src="/getimages.php?n=1531993942_square.jpg&hash=somehash" />
```

So you can just ask if hash is set and valid, then return the image via php, here you'll find some examples: [fpassthru()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru.php). If this is the solution you want, you have to put a `.htaccess` file to you image directory, so no one can directly access the image.

**.htaccess**

```
Deny from all
```

The other solution would be take the links how they are and do a rewrite with `.htaccess`, here you will find some information:

- [Apache - rewrite images to php file with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925567/apache-rewrite-images-to-php-file-with-htaccess)
- [Redirecting image requests via .htaccess depending on file
  existence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26949541/redirecting-image-requests-via-htaccess-depending-on-file-existence)
- [.htaccess rewrite image file to php script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703862/htaccess-rewrite-image-file-to-php-script)

**Example (how it could work):**

**Filetree**

```
public_html
    |--images
       |-- example.jpg
       |-- .htaccess
       |-- image.php
    |-- file that include the images
    |-- some other files
    |-- ....
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*?\.jpe?g|png|gif|ico|bmp)$ image.php?image=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,NC]
```

**image.php**

```
$serveFile = false;
if( isset( $_GET["image"] ) && isset( $_GET["hash"] ) ) {
    // check hash, just for example used md5
    $image = trim( $_GET["image"] );
    $file = dirname( __FILE__ ).'/'.$image;
    $imagehash = md5( $image );

    if( $imagehash === trim( $_GET["hash"] ) && file_exists( $file ) ) {
        // serve the file
        $serveFile = true;
    }
}

if( $serveFile ) {
    // BEWARE you have to send the right header,
    // maybe create an array with the content types for extensions
    // or get a mime type function which returns this i.e.:image/jpg or some other type
    header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize( $file) );
    readfile( $file );
//  exit;
} else {
    // just sends a header, maybe you have to output a 403 page
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    // here you can include your own 403 page
    // include "/path/to/my/403.html";
    exit;
}
```

You should adjust the `.htaccess` to your needs.

Comment: Concerning rewrite all images and serving them through php I guess it would be too heavy for the server especially if the image size is big and I have millions of images.. I was meaning my question regarding the existing example I have mentioned. As you can see they are using direct path to the JPG without php in between. And the question - How do they did this?

Comment: Well then you have to go the htacces way, because someone needs to validate the given hash, this can only be done with a script, I think it this case with a PHP script

Comment: and do you know by chance any php function how to perform the validation and how to serve the images?

Comment: I've updated my answer, with a small approach how it could be solved

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!